# Create 3D logical mask from points

Tags: matlab, points

I have a set of 3D points specifying points on a surface of an object.  From these points, i need to construct a 3D logical mask. How can I solve this with matlab? Hope to get some insights.

Comment: What is the criteria for the logical points?  On surface?  In volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
% parameters
num_coordinates = 100;
max_coordinate = 20;
% generate random coordinate
x = sort(randi(max_coordinate, [num_coordinates, 1]));
y = sort(randi(max_coordinate, [num_coordinates, 1]));
z = sort(randi(max_coordinate, [num_coordinates, 1]));
% create the mask
mask = false(max_coordinate, max_coordinate, max_coordinate);
for k = 1 : length(x)
    mask(x(k), y(k), z(k)) = true;
end
```

If speed is important, I suppose there is a faster solution.

Comment: Let say I have a 100 point in x,y,z coordinate. The matrix is 100x3. Then what will be the num_coordinates & max_coordinates corresponds to? Thnks.

Comment: Using this code it only create a 3d mask on the object boundary, not the whole object. So how can I fill up the mask as similar to imfill function for 3D masking?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the "Curve Fitting Toolbox" you could fit a surface formula to the data.
And if you now the exact type (like a ball, cone, ...) you can define that as formular to fit to.

Maybe you can provide some example data.